# Read all files in a directory and compare the result with a datagrid

Tags: c#, list, streamreader

i need to read a list of files in a given directory (c:/file/test).

I only need to read the second line (always this line).

The file is a .NT940 so i need to open it in notepad (or something else).

I need to open every file in the directory, read the second line and stor it in a list.

```
 public List<FileInfo> Getextraitfile(string fileName)
        {
            List<FileInfo> listData = new List<FileInfo>();
            try
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(fileName))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        string line = reader.ReadLine();

                        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo();
                        fileInfo.DataLine = line;

                        listData.Add(fileInfo);
                    }
                }

                return listData;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.logErreur("GetCsvFile : " + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
                return new List<FileInfo>();
            }
        }
```

I have this to get the nt90 file but i'm totaly lost, can you please help me ?

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: OP might have asked a bit confuse but it is quite clear what he needs. Why the close votes??. This is why SO is being flagged as aggresive to new users. Come on guys.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. In future questions try to specify a little better what you need including examples and more details. I think that something like this will help you:

```
    public List<string> GetLinesOfFile(string folderName)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = new DirectoryInfo(folderName).GetFiles("*.nt940");

        List<string> listYouNeed = new List<string>();

        foreach (FileInfo f in files)
        {
            string[] allLines = File.ReadAllLines(f.FullName);

            listYouNeed.Add(allLines[1]); //HERE YOU READ THE SECOND LINE OF THE FILE
        }

        return listYouNeed;
    }
```

Comment: instead of using ReadAllLines, we should prefer to read till the second line only as other lines are not required